# Starting at a specific row without an ID number?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm writing a code which looks up a MYSQL table, hits an API and then writes the result to a table.

Initially I was using:

```
$select = "SELECT Partner, Merchant, IP FROM " .$old_table.  " WHERE ID >= " .$startRow;
mysqli_query($db, $select);
```

This worked well, but then I realized all the tables I have may not have sequential ID numbers, or even ID numbers at all.

Is there a way to start at a specific row without ID numbers?

Comment: In SQL a data-set (be they a table, results from a query, results from a function, etc, etc) are considered to have no innate order.  The only way to guarantee an order is with an ORDER BY using certain fields in that data-set.  If you have no sequential id, or other fields that yu can use to create an order, this is not possible.

Comment: Which row do you want to start at?

Comment: A  user specified row. From the answer I've gotten, the best thing I've been able to come up with is just to create a counter which fetches rows, not reporting them, until I get to the user specified row and then start returning the values in the rows. Better ideas?

Comment: @user1475765: How does the user specify the row?  How do you know what comes next?

Comment: the user specifies on the html page by inputting into a text box

Comment: It sounds like you can match *something* in the db row, if so you can use that in a where clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rows in SQL aren't necessarily in order.  So without a sequential ID (or other identifier, like a date), there's no way to get all rows after a certain point.

So, no, you can't start at a specific row without a way to ID it, and IDing the rows that should come after it.